# Procedure to recover BTC stuck in 2/2 Multisig

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature, lightning-network-daemon, channels

I opened a 2M Sat Channel and my peer should send me back 1M Sats Onchain, as I have pushed half.

Now unfortunately, I’ve sent my peer the address of the 2/2 Multisig of the funding TX and not the Onchain one :-(

I thought that I would get those Sats back, when I close the channel, but now unfortunately they are stuck.

I’ve been told that it should be theoretically possible to get those Sats back, but as a noob I don’t know how to proceed.

Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance for any reply!

Comment: Ok, I have reactivated the efforts on this one, as I'm now retired and have plenty of time...
Well from an economical point of view it's an absolute "no go" and makes no sense at all, as only 1M sats are stuck and I better would go cleaning toilets to make the money back :-)
But on the other hand I think this would be quite nice learning experience an keep the brain of an old fart going :-)

What would be the first step of the recovery procedure?

Would getting the key pairs (private key and address) that have signed the 2/2 Multisig a good start?